# Erro no Javascript ao selecionar o botão em outra tag

Tags: javascript, html

Toda vez que aperto no Button para criar dentro da section id="secElementos" ele deveria criar um botão,mas não cria, já revisei o código várias vezes e não consigo achar o erro

```
<style>

    section article {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 45%;
        height: 100px;
    }



    header, nav, section, article, footer {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 4px;

    } 
    #navMenu > a:first-child {
       border-left: 1px solid black;

    }

    #navMenu a { 
        bolder-right: 1px solid black;
        }
</style>


<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Teste</title>
```

## Site Dinâmico

```
    </header>

    <nav id="navMenu">

           <a href="#">Pagina</a>
           <a href="#">Pagina</a>

    </nav>


    <section>
        <h2>Criador de Elementos</h2>
        <article>
            <h3>Elementos</h3>
            <button value="p" onclick="criarElemento(this.value) " >p</button>
            <button value="button" onclick="criarElemento(this.value) " >Botão</button>
            <button value="div" onclick="criarElemento(this.value)" >Div</button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h3>Edição de Atributos</h3>
            <p>Elemento: </p>
            <select id="slcDadosElemento" ></select>
        </article>
    </section>

    <section id="secElementos">
            z
    </section>

<footer>
    <p>Aula Teste</p>
</footer>           

    <script>

        function criarElemento(tag) {
            var elemento = document.createElement("tag");
            elemento.innerText = "teste";
            //elemento.onclick = obterAtributosDosElementos;
            elemento.addEventListener("click", obterAtributosDosElementos);
            document.getElementById("secElementos").appendChild(elemento);
        }

        function obterAtributosDosElementos() {
            var select = document.getElementById("slcDadosElemento");
            var chaves = object.keys(this);

            for (var i = 0; i < chaves.length; i++) {
                var opcao = document.createElemente("option");
                opcao.value = chaves[i];
                opcao.innerText = chaves[i];
                select.appendChild(opcao);
            }

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Italo, procure resolver as suas perguntas. Vc já fez 3 perguntas e nenhuma delas vc marcou ✔️ numa resposta. O site funciona assim: vc faz uma pergunta, elege a melhor resposta e marca ✔️. Se nenhuma resposta foi satisfatória, questione quem respondeu, mas não abandone as suas perguntas ou deixe sem solução porque isso não faz parte do propósito do SOpt.

Comment: lembrando que você ganha pontos ao aceitar uma resposta ✔️

Answer (score 0):

Está usando o os nomes errados. Não existe a tag "botão":

```
<button value="button" onclick="criarElemento(this.value) " >Botão</button>
```

E a tag `div` deve ser em minúscula:

```
<button value="div" onclick="criarElemento(this.value)" >Div</button>
```

Aqui também você não deve incluir a variável `tag` entre aspas, senão ela vai ser tratada como uma string e não como o valor do parâmetro da função:

```
var elemento = document.createElement("tag");
```

**Código corrigido:**

```js
function criarElemento(tag) {
   var elemento = document.createElement(tag);
   elemento.innerText = "teste";
   //elemento.onclick = obterAtributosDosElementos;
   elemento.addEventListener("click", obterAtributosDosElementos);
   document.getElementById("secElementos").appendChild(elemento);
}

function obterAtributosDosElementos() {
   var select = document.getElementById("slcDadosElemento");
   var chaves = object.keys(this);

   for (var i = 0; i < chaves.length; i++) {
       var opcao = document.createElemente("option");
       opcao.value = chaves[i];
       opcao.innerText = chaves[i];
       select.appendChild(opcao);
   }

}
```

```html
</header>

    <nav id="navMenu">

           <a href="#">Pagina</a>
           <a href="#">Pagina</a>

    </nav>


    <section>
        <h2>Criador de Elementos</h2>
        <article>
            <h3>Elementos</h3>
            <button value="p" onclick="criarElemento(this.value) " >p</button>
            <button value="button" onclick="criarElemento(this.value)" >button</button>
            <button value="div" onclick="criarElemento(this.value)" >div</button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h3>Edição de Atributos</h3>
            <p>Elemento: </p>
            <select id="slcDadosElemento" ></select>
        </article>
    </section>

    <section id="secElementos">
            z
    </section>

<footer>
    <p>Aula Teste</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Copilou correto, Obrigado Nobre!